# PHP OOP: Job of Authenticator Class to retrieve current user via session?

Tags: php, oop

I'm in the process of reorganizing an application.

At the start of my application I need an object to be initialized to represent the current user. I am planning an authentication class to handle logging in and logging out, and I am wondering if the initial session variable check for user id and database retrieval would be appropriate for this class as well or if there is a standard protocol?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, Of Course. Checking the session variables for user id *at first* is the right thing to do.

No matter what kind of authentication use, at a point you have to check if someone is already logged in or not. It is not even that complicated. For the simplest of use:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['logged_status']) && $_SESSION['logged_status'] ==1) {
    $this -> logged = true;
}
```

However, the database retrieval part as a session variable is not as secured as you want it to be. Although, caches records can be stored in the session without any risk.

Comment: I was thinking more in line of storing the user_id in a session variable so I could use it to retrieve the associated record from the database.

Comment: @christian, Sure its no problem. On that case use something like `.. && $_SESSION['logged_in'] > 0`

Answer (score 0):

Well typically the way i do it is to create a generic WebUser class. This calss is basically the model for the session. So everytime the app runs an instance of it is created. Then on that class ill dop methods like `signIn`/`signOut`, `isAuthenticated` and other things. This class then interacts with the model for authentication which also returns certain attributes of a User entity (like the user_id) for use later. Though i also usually make a convenience getter for the User entity directly on the WebUser class.